# Eagle PCB design how to make flat pins for the power socket

Tags: power, pcb, pcb-design, eaglecad, socket

All the Eagle libraries I have found have round small holes (like for the THT resistors or capacitors). But most of the available ones have flat pins (like this one):

[image]

My question is: How to create this shape hole? Any advice appreciated.

Comment: I usually used "drilled slots" for such parts, most PCB makers can provide them at no additional cost, but I don't use Eagle. It's quite straightforward in Altium. Of course you can just use big holes but it will use a lot of solder and will be weaker than necessary. Earlier versions of Eagle suggested drawing the slots and getting the PCB maker to intervene. The slots are always semicircles at the ends (you don't get to specify end radii).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Two options:

You don't.  Use the smallest round hole that the flat pin is guaranteed to fit thru.

Specify a slot in the routing or maybe dimension layer.  However, contact your board house first to find out how to specify the slot must be plated, which layer they want to see what in, etc.  Be prepared for extra cost.

I've always used option 1 so far.

Comment: Option one is the best I think. Easiest and the cheapest as well

Comment: Option #1 for me too. If anyone wants to go with option #2, the key phrase for your board house is "plated slots"